# Use PHP to list info from a Web Service that's using SOAP

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, soap

I have never used SOAP before (and still wouldn't have if not needed) but I need to make an input search to list info (with the help of php or javascript) from a web service using SOAP and I have [this Query](http://portalquery.just.ro/query.asmx?op=CautareDosare2), the [XML Service Deschiption](http://portalquery.just.ro/query.asmx?WSDL) and the method address:

```
{AdresaInterfata}?op= CautareDosare
```

And this method prototype:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Cautare dosare dupa numar, obiect, institutie")]
        public Dosar[] CautareDosare(
            string numarDosar,
            string obiectDosar,
            string numeParte,
            Institutie? institutie,
            DateTime? dataStart,
            DateTime? dataStop

            )
```

...and I basically don't know where to start or what to do to put these together. This web service contains info of all the justice files and their status/updates and so on. [An example](http://portal.just.ro/SitePages/cautare.aspx?k=2013) of it working is on their own website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Happily for you, this is a problem that has been solved by many before you, so you can benefit from their work.

I have had a lot of success with this project:
https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator

(packaged for composer here: https://packagist.org/packages/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator)

It has a class that you can use to generate SOAP client classes in PHP from a WSDL.  It basically writes code for you that you can just use to make your SOAP calls, effectively abstracting this whole problem away.  They have pretty good documentation as well.  If you're looking for a starting point, that might be a good one as it does a lot of work for you.

If you'd rather start more low level, you can check out PHP's SoapClient class:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

## Wsdl2Php Example

Here is a script I threw together that generates the needed code:

```
<?php
// generate.php

// Include composer autoloader to pull in libraries:
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Generate client code for the web service:
$generator = new \Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Generator();
$generator->generate(
    new \Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Config(array(
        'inputFile' => 'http://portalquery.just.ro/query.asmx?WSDL',
        'outputDir' => '/path/for/generated/code'
    ))
);
```

I then ran that script from the command line, and then went to "/path/for/generated/code" to find the generated classes.

From there I created the following script:

```
<?php
// This line disables the SOAP cache.  This should be removed for production.
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

// Pull in generated class autoloader:
require '/path/for/generated/code/autoload.php';

$query = new Query();
$dateStart = new DateTime('2015-05-01');
$dateStop = new DateTime('2015-05-02');

// This would be a lot easier if I knew Romanian!
$cautareDosare = new CautareDosare("","","",Institutie::CurteadeApelBRASOV,$dateStart,$dateStop);

$results  = $query->CautareDosare($cautareDosare);

?>
<html>
  <body>
    <pre>
<?php var_export($results); ?>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which yielded the following results:

```
CautareDosareResponse::__set_state(array(
   'CautareDosareResult' => 
  ArrayOfDosar::__set_state(array(
     'Dosar' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      Dosar::__set_state(array(
         'parti' => 
        ArrayOfDosarParte::__set_state(array(
           'DosarParte' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            DosarParte::__set_state(array(
               'nume' => 'NEGOIÅ¢Ä‚ LAURA MARIA',
               'calitateParte' => 'Contestator',
            )),
          ),
        )),
         'sedinte' => 
        ArrayOfDosarSedinta::__set_state(array(
           'DosarSedinta' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            DosarSedinta::__set_state(array(
               'complet' => 'JDL(C)3',
               'data' => '2015-05-04T00:00:00',
               'ora' => '10:00',
               'solutie' => 'Respins',
               'solutieSumar' => '
    Respinge contestaÅ£ia declaratÄƒ de inculpata NegoiÅ£Äƒ Laura Maria Ã®mpotriva Ã®ncheierii de ÅŸedinÅ£Äƒ din data de 1 mai 2015 pronunÅ£atÄƒ de JudecÄƒtorul de Drepturi ÅŸi LibertÄƒÅ£i de la Tribunalul pentru Minori ÅŸi Familie BraÅŸov, Ã®n dosar nr. 359/1372/2014, pe care o menÅ£ine.
    ObligÄƒ inculpata sÄƒ plÄƒteascÄƒ statului suma de 100 lei cu titlu de cheltuieli judiciare.
    DefinitivÄƒ.
    PronunÅ£atÄƒ Ã®n camera de consiliu, azi 4 mai 2015.
',
               'dataPronuntare' => '2015-05-04T00:00:00',
               'documentSedinta' => 'incheierefinaladezinvestire',
               'numarDocument' => '48/2015',
               'dataDocument' => '2015-05-04T00:00:00',
            )),
          ),
        )),
         'caiAtac' => NULL,
         'numar' => '229/64/2015',
         'numarVechi' => '',
         'data' => '2015-05-01T18:29:00',
         'institutie' => 'CurteadeApelBRASOV',
         'departament' => 'SecÅ£ia PenalÄƒ',
         'categorieCaz' => 'Penal',
         'stadiuProcesual' => 'ContestaÅ£ieNCPP',
         'obiect' => 'audierea inculpatului arestat Ã®n lipsÄƒ (art.231 NCPP)',
         'dataModificare' => '2015-05-04T15:01:24.613',
         'categorieCazNume' => 'Penal',
         'stadiuProcesualNume' => 'ContestaÅ£ie(NCPP)',
      )),
      1 => 
      Dosar::__set_state(array(
         'parti' => 
        ArrayOfDosarParte::__set_state(array(
           'DosarParte' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            DosarParte::__set_state(array(
               'nume' => 'VULCAN HORAÅ¢IU-ADRIAN',
               'calitateParte' => 'Contestator Inculpat',
            )),
            1 => 
            DosarParte::__set_state(array(
               'nume' => 'HANGHICEL MARIUS-FLORIN',
               'calitateParte' => 'Contestator Inculpat',
            )),
            2 => 
            DosarParte::__set_state(array(
               'nume' => 'PÃŽRÅ¢AC ANDREI',
               'calitateParte' => 'Contestator Inculpat',
            )),
            3 => 
            DosarParte::__set_state(array(
               'nume' => 'URDEA EMIL',
               'calitateParte' => 'Intimat Inculpat',
            )),
            4 => 
            DosarParte::__set_state(array(
               'nume' => 'PARCHETUL DE PE LÃ‚NGÄ‚ ÃŽNALTA CURTE DE CASAÅ¢IE ÅžI JUSTIÅ¢IE - D.I.I.C.O.T. - SERVICIUL TERITORIAL BRAÅžOV',
               'calitateParte' => 'Contestator',
            )),
          ),
        )),
         'sedinte' => 
        ArrayOfDosarSedinta::__set_state(array(
           'DosarSedinta' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            DosarSedinta::__set_state(array(
               'complet' => 'JDL(C)10',
               'data' => '2015-05-04T00:00:00',
               'ora' => '9:00',
               'solutie' => 'Admis',
               'solutieSumar' => ' ÃŽn baza art. 204 Cod procedurÄƒ penalÄƒ ÅŸi art. 425 indice 1 alineat 7 punct 2 litera a Cod de procedurÄƒ penalÄƒ admite contestaÅ£ia formulatÄƒ de Parchetul de pe lÃ¢ngÄƒ ÃŽnalta Curte de CasaÅ£ie ÅŸi JustiÅ£ie - DIICOT- Serviciul Teritorial BraÅŸov Ã®mpotriva Ã®ncheierii nr. 46/UP/30.04.2015 pronunÅ£atÄƒ de judecÄƒtorul de drepturi ÅŸi libertÄƒÅ£i din cadrul Tribunalului BraÅŸov Ã®n dosarul penal nr. 1820/62/2015, pe care o desfiinÅ£eazÄƒ cu privire la soluÅ£ionarea propunerii de arestare preventivÄƒ Ã®n ceea ce-l priveÅŸte pe inculpatul Urdea Emil.
RejudecÃ¢nd Ã®n aceste limite:
ÃŽn baza art. 204 alineat 10 ÅŸi art. 226 Cod de procedurÄƒ penalÄƒ admite propunerea de arestare preventivÄƒ formulatÄƒ de Parchetul de pe lÃ¢ngÄƒ ÃŽnalta Curte de CasaÅ£ie ÅŸi JustiÅ£ie - DIICOT- Serviciul Teritorial BraÅŸov ÅŸi Ã®n consecinÅ£Äƒ, Ã®n baza art. 202 alineat 1, 3 ÅŸi 4 litera e Cod de procedurÄƒ penalÄƒ, art. 223 alineat 2 teza a II a Cod de procedurÄƒ penalÄƒ dispune arestarea preventivÄƒ pe o duratÄƒ de 30 de zile, Ã®ncepÃ¢nd cu data punerii Ã®n executare a mandatului de arestare preventivÄƒ, a inculpatului Urdea Emil. Dispune emiterea mandatului de arestare preventivÄƒ a inculpatului Urdea Emil.
ÃŽn baza art. 425 indice 1 alineat 7 punct 1 litera b Cod de procedurÄƒ penalÄƒ respinge ca nefondate contestaÅ£iile formulate de inculpaÅ£ii Vulcan HoraÅ£iu Adrian, PÃ®rÅ£ac Andrei ÅŸi Hanghicel Marius Florin Ã®mpotriva Ã®ncheierii nr. 46/UP/30.04.2015 pronunÅ£atÄƒ de judecÄƒtorul de drepturi ÅŸi libertÄƒÅ£i din cadrul Tribunalului BraÅŸov Ã®n dosarul penal nr. 1820/62/2015 ÅŸi menÅ£ine dispoziÅ£iile referitoare la aceÅŸti inculpaÅ£i.
ÃŽn baza art. 275 alineat 2 Cod de procedurÄƒ penalÄƒ obligÄƒ inculpaÅ£ii  Vulcan HoraÅ£iu Adrian, PÃ®rÅ£ac Andrei ÅŸi Hanghicel Marius Florin la plata fiecare a sumei de 100 de lei reprezentÃ¢nd cheltuieli judiciare avansate de stat, restul cheltuielilor avansate de stat rÄƒmÃ¢nÃ¢nd Ã®n sarcina acestuia.
DefinitivÄƒ.
    PronunÅ£atÄƒ Ã®n ÅŸedinÅ£Äƒ camerei de consiliu azi, 04.05.2015
',
               'dataPronuntare' => '2015-05-04T00:00:00',
               'documentSedinta' => 'incheierefinaladezinvestire',
               'numarDocument' => '50/2015',
               'dataDocument' => '2015-05-04T00:00:00',
            )),
          ),
        )),
         'caiAtac' => 
        ArrayOfDosarCaleAtac::__set_state(array(
           'DosarCaleAtac' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            DosarCaleAtac::__set_state(array(
               'dataDeclarare' => '2015-04-30T00:00:00',
               'parteDeclaratoare' => '',
               'tipCaleAtac' => 'ContestaÅ£ie(NCPP)',
            )),
            1 => 
            DosarCaleAtac::__set_state(array(
               'dataDeclarare' => '2015-04-30T00:00:00',
               'parteDeclaratoare' => ' HANGHICEL MARIUS-FLORIN,  PÃŽRÅ¢AC ANDREI,  VULCAN HORAÅ¢IU-ADRIAN, ',
               'tipCaleAtac' => 'ContestaÅ£ie(NCPP)',
            )),
          ),
        )),
         'numar' => '1820/62/2015',
         'numarVechi' => '',
         'data' => '2015-05-01T15:13:00',
         'institutie' => 'CurteadeApelBRASOV',
         'departament' => 'SecÅ£ia PenalÄƒ',
         'categorieCaz' => 'Penal',
         'stadiuProcesual' => 'ContestaÅ£ieNCPP',
         'obiect' => 'luarea mÄƒsurii arestÄƒrii preventive propusÄƒ de DNA/DIICOT (art.223 NCPP)',
         'dataModificare' => '2015-06-15T10:10:12.637',
         'categorieCazNume' => 'Penal',
         'stadiuProcesualNume' => 'ContestaÅ£ie(NCPP)',
      )),
    ),
  )),
))
```

Comment: This may be something to work with but, like I said, I never used SOAP therefore I have no idea on what and where to put, how to configure and so on. I started reading and looking into what you offered but still...:(

Comment: @Alin, all soap is is a method of calling a function on a different machine, and getting the results back to use on yours. Most languages have a construct to abstract that part of the problem away so you don't even really see it. With whatever system you go with, you end up calling a function or object method as if it were your own.  I've added an example of using the wsdl2php library to abstract away your SOAP problem.  This bring the problem back into the domain of dealing with standard PHP objects and method calls.  I hope this helps. =)

Answer (score 1):

try to explore this link, to Connect to the Web Service API using PHP

```
  http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/connecting_to_the_api_using_php/
```

and in place of the below url

```
$wsdl = 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl';
```

replace with

```
$wsdl = 'http://portalquery.just.ro/query.asmx?WSDL';
```